# Javascript string parsing issue

Tags: javascript

I have a string that when printed looks like this
"fname XYZ mname {} lname ABC"

Its stored as a single string in the code. Not as an object. 
But I want to be able to individually access fname, mname and lname. How can I print fname, mname and lname separately ? is there an easy way or should I be storing the string as an object for easy access to fname, mname, lname ?

Comment: Sounds like an object would be a reasonable choice here.

Comment: You need an object.

Comment: Split the string on the spaces then take the first, third, and fifth elements.

Comment: Thanks j08691. Thats what Jecons suggested and thats what I think I will do. An object would be another choice.

Answer (score 1):

If they are all separated by a space, then you can split the string into an array of strings.

```
var inputString = "fname XYZ mname {} lname ABC";
var strings = inputString.split(" "); // outputs ["fname", "XYZ", "mname", "{}", "lname", "ABC"]
```

Comment: They are all separated by a single space. I think converting to array and then accessing by [1] [3] and [5] would give me the values for fname, mname and lname.

Comment: Then yes, that'd be the easiest way. Remember that array indices are zero-based. (fname will be strings[0])

Comment: Yep. Thanks Jecoms.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain an associative array like this :

```
var str = "fname XYZ mname {} lname ABC";
var obj = [];
str.split(" ").forEach((item, index, arr) => {if (index%2 === 0) obj[item] = arr[index+1]}) ;
console.log(obj); // [ fname: 'XYZ', mname: '{}', lname: 'ABC' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Install: https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-saw

You can do this:

```
let string = 'fname XYZ mname {} lname ABC';
let stringObj = saw(string)
  .split(' ')
  .filter(item => !item.match(/name/i))
  .toObject('fname', 'mname', 'lname')
```

Now you have an object and these values are easily accessible.

```
{
"fname": "XYZ",
"mname": "{}",
"lname": "ABC"
}
```